# Collect a list of open data systems

Tags: data-request, tool-request

for a research project we are trying to collect a list of relevant open data systems. I am aware that *systems* is very broad so I tried to categorize them a bit.

Please help us extending this list with other relevant systems.

Here is what we have collected so far:

## Open Data catalog software

- [CKAN](http://ckan.org/)
- [Socrata](http://www.socrata.com/)
- [Open Spending](https://openspending.org/)
- [The Datatank](http://thedatatank.com/)
- [DKAN](http://nucivic.com/dkan/) (CKAN clone in Drupal)
- [ArcGIS Open Data](https://opendata.arcgis.com)

  ## Data processing
- [Fusion tables](http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html#fusiontables)
- [Open Refine](http://openrefine.org/)
- [Data wrangler](http://vis.stanford.edu/wrangler/)
- [R](http://www.r-project.org) and [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com)

## Visualization

- [Many Eyes](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/analytics/manyeyes/)
- [Datawrapper](http://datawrapper.de/)

## Collaboration

- [GitHub](https://github.com/)
- [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

## Databases

- [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org)
- [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/)
- [Open Streemap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)
- [Worldbank](http://data.worldbank.org/)
- [Governmental data portals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_data#Open_data_in_government)
- [DataCatalogs](http://datacatalogs.org/)
- [OpenGeoCode](http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/)
- [List of CKAN instances](http://ckan.org/instances/)
- [Azure data market](http://datamarket.azure.com/)
- [Outpan Product Database](http://www.outpan.com/)

Comment: I think this is an excellent questions that should  be splitted into questions per type of tool (databases, processing, catalog software) so the conversation remain focused.

Comment: @magdmartin - I added a while back ago a Question and my own Answer to formats for exchanging open data catalogs. - http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/format-for-exchanging-open-data-catalogs

Comment: Don't forget ArcGIS Open Data as Catalog Software, https://opendata.arcgis.com
Full disclosure: I am a product engineer at ESRI

Answer (score 6):

I've compiled a fairly extensive list of open government portals both in US and around the world in the last few days. I am working on code to support crowdsourcing the catalog. I also have a CSV version for download. There is about 700 sites listed so far:

ONLINE CATALOG: http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/

DOWNLOAD: http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/opendata.csv

I've setup the catalog for crowdsourcing, so feel free to send us your suggested portals to add to the catalog.

Comment: @andrew-opengeocode why is barcelona under Italy?

Comment: Also you may add [Open Data datasets of the autonomous Province of Bolzano](https://opengisdata.eu/datasets)

Comment: @Ulrich - I fixed the Barcelona link and added Bolzano. thx.

Answer (score 4):

There's an epic list of text-processing and text-mining tools at the [Bamboo DiRT wiki](http://dirt.projectbamboo.org/). Go to town!

Comment: These are tools. Asker is asking for data.

Comment: The initial list contains quite a few tools and tool suites (e.g. under "Data processing" and "Visualization"). I'm not sure how you arrived at your conclusion.

Comment: OK I was mistaken sorry! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Civic Dynamics- CDP is a proven, open-source turnkey software platform for managing and publishing open, community data. It is used for local government data and community indicator systems.  It enables the publishing of open data in a dynamic format that allows citizens to easily view, mix, match and download data for analysis, as well as contribute their own information and thoughts - thereby facilitating true citizen engagement.  Given these attributes, it is recommended that CDP would fit under two of the identified categories:

1. Open Data Catalog software: http://civic-dynamics.com/
2. Visualization:http://civic-dynamics.com/

Comment: Kelly, so that people are well-informed, we ask that people disclose in each message when they have a relationship w/ a project or company that they're mentioning.  (see http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/behavior , under 'self-promotion').  You've done it in your user profile, but we ask that people put it specifically in their answers that may have a conflict of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no api at the moment but it's coming soon ;)

I found this "Wikipedia of numbers" yesterday:
http://meterfy.com

Comment: Okay sorry for the "soon" guys! I really believed that they are working on it... https://help.meterfy.com/hc/en-us/articles/200423551-Is-there-an-API-

Answer (score 2):

Geonode @ http://geonode.org for the sharing of open geospatial data. Might want to also check out the US governments Open Data Project on github sorry don't have the URL handy

Answer (score 2):

Self serving and a wip, but my baby nevertheless :) (Collaboration)

Exversion is open data infrastructure. It allows people to create data repositories same way they might create code repositories on github (for example) and share this data with everybody or with a select group of individuals. Any additions or changes made to the data are recorded in the version history, can be rolled back and data repos can copied into new branches to produce different versions of the same information. Like I said, work in progress but that's the general idea :)

https://www.exversion.com

Comment: Can you expand this so it's more understandable?

Comment: It's not clear to me that Exversion qualifies as an open data system, but maybe if you expanded per Jeanne's recommendation you could explain that to us.

Comment: Yeah no prob. Exversion is open data infrastructure. It allows people to create data repositories same way they might create code repositories on github (for example) and share this data with everybody or with a select group of individuals. Any additions or changes made to the data are recorded in the version history, can be rolled back and data repos can copied into new branches to produce different versions of the same information. Like I said, work in progress but that's the general idea :)