# Open data & perl

Tags: tool-request, programming

Know anybody about (more or less) complex toolset like

- CKAN / DKAN
- Socrata

which is mainly programmed in the Perl language?

Comment: yes.  do you have a specific question here, or do you just want to know if such people exist?

Comment: @jm666: you might want to take a look at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/collect-a-list-of-open-data-systems but I don't know of any CKAN/Socrata equivalents that are written in Perl. In fact, don't know of many modern web applications written in Perl. All this being said, both CKAN and Socrata have very standardized APIs for all installations which can be accessed using Perl. Let me know if you want more details about that (and what you're trying to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are any specifically in this field ... however, as catalogs go, there are [Koha](http://koha-community.org/) and [Evergreen](http://evergreen-ils.org/), which are ILS systems (Integrated Library Systems).

It might be possible to modify them for use in data cataloging ... you'd likely need to change out the underlying schemas, as I assume they'd be using MARC.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/… but I don't know of any CKAN/Socrata equivalents that are written in Perl. In fact, don't know of many modern web applications written in Perl.

All this being said, both CKAN and Socrata have very standardized APIs for all installations which can be accessed using Perl. Let me know if you want more details about that (and what you're trying to do)

- [Socrata Perl client](http://search.cpan.org/~ovenman/WWW-Socrata-0.01/lib/WWW/Socrata.pm)
- [CKAN Perl client](https://github.com/lukec/net-ckan)

Comment: "In fact, don't know of many modern web applications written in Perl."  That's because most of us writing Perl don't try to pretend that announcing that it's been written in the latest fad programming language is a selling point.  (I worked with a guy who used to make posters about how great a project was because it was open source & written in Python ... he spent more time talking about those two points than than *what features it had* and *why people should use it*)